# How to sum various data attr and values from inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have various inputs, each with a different price via data-attribute:

```
 <%= f.number_field :item, class: "test", :data => {:price => '10.25'}
```

User can select the number of items they want, so I need to multiply the number of items selected by the price of the item.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".test").on('change', function() {
    a = $(".test").val() * $(".test").data("price") + "€";
    $(".resultado").html(a);
  });
});
```

This works great for 1 input, but since I have 4 inputs, each with a different price, I need to get the TOTAL price for the 9 of them.

```
<%= f.number_field :item, class: "test", :data => {:price => '10.25'} %>
<%= f.number_field :seconditem, class: "test", :data => {:price => '10'} %>
<%= f.number_field :thirditem, class: "test", :data => {:price => '10.75'} %>
<%= f.number_field :fourthitem, class: "test", :data => {:price => '10.50'} %>
```

Basically, I need to get this:

```
A: Number of items * price of each item
Sum all of the "A" values
```

How can I modify my script / classes in order to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each item has a different price and quantity, the following refactoring should work.  [Here's a JSFiddle with the working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/heybignick/wpe0fch3/1/).

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".test").on('change', function() {
    var total = 0;
    $.each( $('.test'), function( key, value ) {
      total += $(this).val() * $(this).data("price");
    });
    $(". resultado").html(total + "€");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.each()` to multiply value returned `.data()`

```js
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {

  let n = 1;

  $(".test").each(function() {
    n *= $(this).data().price;
  });

  $(".resultado").html(n);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="button" value="click" />
<div class="test" data-price="1"></div>
<div class="test" data-price="2"></div>
<div class="test" data-price="3"></div>
<div class="test" data-price="4"></div>

<div class="resultado"></div>
```